# No local console (just Ubuntu start screen) after today's kernel update to 3.0.0.14

Tags: 11.10, kernel, updates, console

Most services are running, and I can ssh to it without problems. Just have no local consoles (cannot CTRL+ALT+F1,F2...) and no graphic session either....

Looks like somethings not playing nice with the new kernel, but, how do I trace it?

Comment: excellent & well done.  Please post your answer in the answers section.  In 8 hours time you will be able to accept the answer by clicking the tick symbol next to your answer.  We will also have the opportunity to upvote you as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering myself (as recommended ;-) ):

**The nvidia drivers must be rebuilt after kernel upgrade** (and BTW, dahdi drivers also).

I got local console access sending some CTRL+ALT+F1 *BEFORE* the nvidia driver was actually loaded into the kernel. That way I learnt it was some misbehaviour of the driver preventing me from falling back to consoles later.

Just `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current` and `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` did it for me.
Also: `sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/dkms.postinst reconfigure` did it for dahdi.

Cheers!